# Symmetric key transfer Vs asymmetric for encryption and signing on mobile device

Tags: soap, encryption-asymmetric, encryption-symmetric

**Scenario**

A SOAP web service provides an interface for retrieving documents and data. Security is paramount.

WS-Security is used and both the client and server encrypt and sign the entire SOAP envelope.

**Questions**

Should the private key used for signing be compiled into the application and stored on the device or should it provided by the server using a key exchange protocol (perhaps after authentication of the user)?

Should the private key for decryption be stored on the device or provided by the server?

Is it realistic to have a unique key for each file that is to be decrypted by the server (if uploading from client) or decrypted by the client (if downloading from server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple suggestions:

-You should consider symmetric keys embedded into anything outside your server as public due to reverse engineering (i.e. don't bother even encrypting if the key is out in the wild).

-You should use a per-session symmetric key generated by a secure RNG on the client, and transmitted to the server encrypted with the global asymmetric public key.  Private keys have a shelf-life.

-You can use the session key for all files/streams transferred in that session, but you should use a unique nonce to salt the symmetric-key encryption for each file.  Depending on the encryption mode, using the same key/nonce with more than one stream can leave you vulnerable to XOR'ing the two streams and recovering a mashed-together but unencrypted result.

Answer (score 0):

The entire concept of a private key is defeated if it has to be transmitted from one device to another. Each end of the communication channel must generate their own private keys. Note, that this doesn't mean compiling private keys into an executable, because then everyone with the executable shares a private key, which is obviously not what you want. Each individual device has to use a [cryptographically secure source of random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) to generate it's own public/private key pair. Then public keys can be exchanged in the clear, you can use them to exchange session keys (which can be unique for each and every file), private keys can sign, and everybody is happy.

But remember: Never, ever hard code private keys, and never, ever share them with anybody.

Comment: Are there standard libraries that exist for iOS that provide  cryptographically secure random numbers or provide key pair generation? A quick Google (https://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=aca&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ios+private+key+pair+generation) didn't show up much.

Comment: I've never done iOS development, but [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/CryptographicServices/CryptographicServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH3-SW1), and specifically [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007281) look like what you need.